# Why cannot compress all files with find and zip?

Tags: shell, find, zip, xargs

I have the following folder structure

```
.
├── 5.avi
├── a
│   ├── 1.avi
│   ├── b
│   │   └── 2.avi
│   └── c
│       └── 3.avi
└── b
    ├── 4.avi
    ├── l
    └── s
```

I am using the following command to compress all `avi` files:

```
find .  -iname *avi | xargs zip videos.zip
```

The problem is that `find` only returns `5.avi`, but if the `5.avi` doesn't exist, `find` returns the rest of the files.

How can solve it and comprime all `avi` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell expands asterisks (`*`) before it passes the arguments to the command (`find` in your case). The actual command will look like

```sh
find . -iname 5.avi
```

You can test that by prepending `echo` to your command, e.g.

```sh
echo find . -iname *avi
```

What you want to do is passing `*avi` as-is to the command. For that, you must put the asterisk in quotes, or escape it with a backslash. Your command should be:

```sh
find . -iname '*.avi' | xargs zip videos.zip
```

Comment: Nice answer. Elaborating a little further: when the shell tries to expand a pattern and there are no matches, the default behaviour is that the pattern remains verbatim as a string (test: `echo 5* 6*`). This behaviour can be controlled with the `nullglob` shell setting (`help shopt`)